# trying to get up and running with andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I tried the stuff here,

http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/getting-started-with-andengine-t11.html

- jar file 404s
- I checked out the AndEngineExamples and I can't run it because "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application"

How can I start running examples utilizing AndEngine?

Answer (score 1):

Have you included library for AndEngine - [AndEngine from Scratch (I)](http://andenginefromscratch.blogspot.com/2011/03/introduccion-andengine-parte-i.html)

Comment: apparently, any jar files are no longer up to date, as that's not how they release it anymore (according to their forums)

Answer (score 0):

didn't have api 8, only 7 and 14.. this caused errors when checking out AndEngine and AndEngineExamples